# How to add a multiple dates attribute to a product in magento?

Tags: arrays, list, date, magento

Simply put; The user should be able to see whether the item (to rent) is available on the needed day- when looking at product details.

The admin can set the date**s** where the item is booked already, 
so that the visitors can see this in a calendar in the front end.

Comment: The best way I could think of at the moment is to use a text area type and store all the values with a special delimiter; as said by: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545494/magento-single-custom-product-attribute-with-array-of-values), but there should be a neater way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?